# set mark on iptables based on interface

Tags: iptables, nat

I have an Ubuntu 10.04 machine with two ethernet interfaces: eth0 (WAN) eth1 (LAN)

I've configured NAT using these commands:

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -i eth1 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE
```

Now I'd like to add a packet mark to packets sourced from eth1 so that I can traffic-shape based on the mark.  What iptables commands do I need to do this?

It seems like I need something along the lines of

```
   sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -t mangle -j MARK --set-mark 3
```

But I'm not sure.  I want to make sure this mark persists past the nat so that I can inspect packets going out on eth0 with tc to do traffic shaping.

Comment: Shouldn't your MASQUERADE rule be a bit more... specific? Or are you really intending to MASQUERADE all packets coming into your LAN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -t mangle -j MARK --set-mark 3
```

you want to have the packets marked before they go into the router so you can use PREROUTING.
see as well http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.netfilter.html